# Android studio AVD glitch

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, android-studio-2.0

I am new to android studio. Literally its my first day on the software. I am having issue with AVD Screen
I have used the default pixel 3 avd to run the apk but here is the problem:-
SO here is the
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIFbI.jpg) and here is the
[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnWZK.jpg)
. I am sorry if it has any silly mistake but please help me it will make my day ❤

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#454545"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="385dp"
    android:layout_height="41dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/black_ops_one"
    android:shadowColor="#70000000"
    android:shadowDx="10"
    android:shadowDy="5"
    android:shadowRadius="1"
    android:text="              Sumant Dusane"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:translationZ="5dp"
    android:typeface="normal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="295dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="435dp"
    android:alpha="0.2"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:scaleX="15"
    android:translationZ="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/marble_texture" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="447dp"
    android:layout_height="799dp"
    android:alpha="0.5"
    android:scaleY="1.9"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.25"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/matte_painitng_corrected__main" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="41dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="41dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="29dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="29dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView6"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/instagram" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="219dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/frank_ruhl_libre_medium"
    android:text="@s.u.m.a.n.t_8282"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView5"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView5" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="49dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="49dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="29dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="29dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="57dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView6"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView5"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.52"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView5"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/linkedin" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="210dp"
    android:layout_height="31dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="26dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/frank_ruhl_libre_medium"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="5sp"
    android:text="Sumant Dusane"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView6"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView6"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView6" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="106dp"
    android:text="Follow for more !!"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView6" />
```

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

Comment: I don't think that's a glitch, dragging and dropping elements might not guarantee that they are output as they are shown in the layout editor. You need to make sure they are constrained well in their xml code, can you please post your xml code here

Comment: Sure brother and yes there was an error regarding to constraints

Comment: Yes i have uploaded the code.And yes there was an error regarding constraints that   
**This view is not constrained, it only has design time positions, so it will jump to (0,0) unless you add constraints**

Comment: Okay, great, glad it worked

Comment: No it didn't worked